# maximum differenence between two column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

there is need to compare two column value find and want to find out difference between this two column value and at the end , want to display all the values present in that table where we find out maximum difference

```
companyname     open    close   date
A                 10      9.8   2015-01-01
A                 11      8.2   2015-02-01 
A                9.8     6.5    2015-02-04
B                 10      8     2015-04-01
B                 9.9    9.5    2015-04-15
C                 8.7    2.3    2015-02-01
```

now I want query which show output

```
company name    open    close  difference  date
A                9.8     6.5     3.3       2015-02-04
B                 10      8       2        2015-04-01
c                 8.7     2.3    6.4       2015-02-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the self-join in [@TimBiegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286110/44853), you can use a windowing function to order by the difference partitioned by `companyname`, then select the first row from each partition:

```
select [companyname] as [company name], [open], [close], [difference], [date]
from (
    select [companyname], [open], [close], 
        [open] - [close] as [difference], [date],
        row_number() over (partition by [companyname] 
                           order by [open] - [close] desc) rn
    from Table1
) x
where rn = 1
```

[[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57722/2)]

Answer (score 3):

A simple `INNER JOIN` of your original table to a subquery obtaining the maximum differences for each company is all you need.

```
SELECT c1.companyname, c1.open, c1.close, c2.maxTime AS difference, c1.date
FROM companies c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT companyname, MAX(open - close) AS maxTime
    FROM companies
    GROUP BY companyname
) c2
ON c1.companyname = c2.companyname AND (c1.open - c1.close) = c2.maxTime
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo** (courtesy of @lc.):

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57722/4)

Comment: hii now as I observe result set carefully I found out there are many companies which are get selected multiple times kindly rectify that error

Comment: I just tested my query using the SQL fiddle provided by @lc. and it runs fine. What is the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
select 
    [companyname],
    [open],
    [close],
    [open] - [close] diff,
    [date]
From (
    select 
        [companyname],
        [open],
        [close],
        [date],
        rank() over (partition by [companyname] order by [open] - [close] desc) rnk
    From my_table
) x
where rnk = 1
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c59c/2)

Comment: Yes, If more than one companies have the same maximum difference. If that is not what you want then use `row_number` instead of `rank`